# Why can't I use QList::size_type as I would std::string::size_type? (template parameter error)

Tags: c++, qt, templates, class-template, dependent-name

While researching an unsigned vs. signed integer comparison warning when declaring an iterator in my for loop, [I read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660901/a-warning-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned-integer-expressions):

> Whenever possible, use the exact type you will be comparing against (for example, use `std::string::size_type` when comparing with a `std::string`'s length).

I have a `QList<T>` I wanted to iterate over, declaring the iterator using the above method:

```
 for(QList::size_type i = 0; i < uploads.size(); i++)
 {
     //Do something
 }
```

And it gave me a compiler error:

```
error: 'template<class T> class QList' used without template parameters
for(QList::size_type i = 0; i < uploads.size(); i++)
```

Why can't I use it the same way? Is this caused by me or by Qt framework and its types? What is a good substitute for `QList::size_type` in this case, `QList::size()` just returns a regular old `int` and I wanted to use that; but I read the post linked above and it made me unsure.

Comment: alternatively, would you have any change use `auto`?

Comment: @appleapple How to use `auto` here? `auto i = 0` seems wrong.

Comment: @songyuanyao sorry you are right. maybe a range based for `for(auto& x : uploads)`?

Comment: @appleapple For `auto i = 0;`, the type of `i` will be `int`; that's not the *exact type* what OP wants.

Comment: to OP: maybe you can use `begin()` and `end()` instead. or `decltype`.

Comment: If fact, the [qt document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#size) says it return int, not `size_type`. So in my opinion, you should not use `size_type` here.

Comment: @appleapple QList<T>::size_type is int

Comment: @Caleth yes it is (now), but the function is itself return `int` not `size_type` (although they *might* be the same)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QList` is a class template, that means you should specify the template argument when use it, e.g. `QList<int>` and `QList<int>::size_type`.

BTW: `std::string` is an instantiation of [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which is a typedef defined as `std::basic_string<char>`. So `std::string::size_type` is equivalent to `std::basic_string<char>::size_type` in fact.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use it in the same way because they are not the same thing.  A `std::string` is actually an alias for `std::basic_string<char>`, that is why you do not have to specify a template type when using it.

Since `Qlist` is not an alias and is a template type you have to use

```
QList<some_type>::size_type
```

One thing you could do is make your own alias like

```
using QIntList = QList<int>;
```

And then you can ise

```
QIntList::size_type
```