# `std::swap` doesn't work as intended in string manipulation

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, encryption, stdstring

I have tried to make basic string encryption, by swapping two consecutive letters.
And it didn't really work as I intended.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string str = "This is a simple string.";
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
        std::swap(str[i], str[i + 1]);
    }
    std::cout << str;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I want to actually swap two near letters, so it will look like encrypted.
The Current result is

```
his is a simple string.
```

Comment: Undefined behavior, due to indexing past the end of the `str` (when `i == str.length ()`, and `i == str.length () - 1`).

Comment: This:  " for (int i = 0; i <= (str.length()-2); i++)  " results in output  "his is a simple string.T".    Understand swap better?  (It is not a good encryption.)

Comment: Also, the correct header for `std::string` is `<string>`, not `<string.h>`.

Comment: To be more precise, here are the [dangers of using the incorrect string header](https://rextester.com/SUJ69640).  Your program fails to compile in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were aiming for something like:

```
std::string str = "This is a simple string.";
for (int i = 0; i <= str.length()-2; i+=2) 
{
    std::swap(str[i], str[i + 1]);
}
std::cout << str;
```

with output

```
hTsii  s aispmels rtni.g
```

Comment: Maybe something like `for (size_t i = 0; !str.empty() && i < str.length() - 1; i++)` to handle empty messages, too.

Comment: Yes ... my code offering has UB when "str.size() < 2" ... I leave it for the OP

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have out of bound access because of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) 
//                ^^^^
```

hence the [behavior of your program is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds). 
You want to iterate one past the size of the string. In addition to that, loop only if the string is not empty(*credits @jww*).

Secondly, there is a comparison between `int` and `unsigend int`(i.e. `str.length()`) [which is also not you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660901/a-warning-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned-integer-expressions).

Last but not least, add the proper header for `std::string`(*as @PaulMcKenzie pointed out in the comments*).

Altogether, you probably want this

```
#include <string>

for (std::size_t i = 0; !str.empty() && i < str.size()-1; i += 2) {
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^
    std::swap(str[i], str[i + 1]);
}
```