C++ library behave differently in release and debug modes
Background
I have a C++ shared library which I build by myself and use it in my own application. This library is written to read files and do modifications. It is using functions like fread, fseek and also have a version string defined as const char* const APP_VERSION = _T(“LIB.LA2.00.00.01”). I use CMake file to build my library and app in remote Linux machine. I use CMake settings to define release and debug modes. In the application, I use release or debug library according to the configuration I select in Visual Studio.
Issue
When I build my library in debug mode, it works fine with my application. But when I build it in release mode, It doesn’t work properly. When I print my app version, It shows 'LIB.VA2.02.02.00' and fread functions are also not working (i.e. file read size is zero).
Things I did

Introduced comparison flags and disabled the compression in lib-release mode using the CMake file. - Got same issue.
Copied source files of the library to the app and compiled together. - Issue got fixed.
Checked any memory leaks in release mode using valgrind. - Nothing found.
Enabled advanced warnings flag (-Wall) and checked for warnings. No major warning found other than unused variables and comparison of different signedness: const int and long unsigned int. Unused variables are related to assert.
Example:

int result = pthread_cond_init(&event->CVariable, 0);
assert(result == 0);

I want to know how can I debug these kind of issues and how to fix my particular issue.

Note that assert is really a macro that typically does nothing in release builds. Which is good since if the assertion fails then it will crash the program, which isn't very nice for the users of your program. Also, C or C++? They are two very different languages.

Regarding the APP_VERSION thing, I assume you use _T to handle wide/narrow character strings? Then why do you always use the narrow character type char? Also, those quotes aren't from your actual code, which means you haven't copy-pasted the code which makes us not trust it. Also please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of both your code and your CMakeLists.txt file.

@Someprogrammerdude Quote: "Which is good since if the assertion fails then it will crash the program, which isn't very nice for the users of your program." On the other hand it's not very nice to continue the program if a basic assetion failed. Proper error handling would be better.

Your program has "undefined behaviour". It just happens not to show in debug mode - only in release mode. Most likely due to extra optimization in release mode. You can try a static code analyzer on your code. Maybe it can find something.

Trditional debuggers can be hard to use on highly optimized code so instead you could give the good old "printf"-debugger a chance. Otherwise, try to identify a small portion of the code where you see an error. Then make a minimal program using exactly that code and still has the error. Perhaps it can be made so small that you can post the code here.

And... "No major warning ... " Get rid of all warnings no matter what. For signedness comparison see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660928/4386427
